# Magento Quote Duplicate value coming

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, session, quote, onestepcheckout

I just need to find the categories of item in cart.
For that I've used:

```
class MageCustom_ShippingFilter_Model_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping
{
    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        if (!$this->_checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request)) {
            return $this;
        }
        return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }

    protected function _checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request = null)
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $i=0;
        $productName = array();
        foreach ($cart as $item) {
            $productName[$i] = $item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds()[0];
            $i++;
        }

        $cat = array(94,97);
        $cartCat = productName;
        $result=array_diff($cat,$cartCat);
        if(count($result)==0){
            //echo count($result);
            if($carrierCode == "southeastern"){
                return true;
            }
        }

        if(count($result)>=1){
            //echo count($result); 
            if($carrierCode == "fedex"){ 
                return true;
        }
    }

}
```

But it's iterating as per cart item.
Like if I add product in cart with same category 10 item, then it's iterating 10 times.

[image]

Here you can see many arrays coming.
I'm getting category name, but I do not know why is coming several times.

Comment: Where did you add this code? Also paste the whole code.

Comment: <p>Did you used any new extension or observer using in your project because generally it does not happen.can you tell more?,it is happening from other code that is interrupting during getting quote data.</p>

Comment: @SukumarGorai Code Updated

Comment: Check from where you are calling your function. Seems like your function is calling several times or you can check how many times the collectCarrierRates function  gets called.